How can I ensure my verified message correctly wraps the original message using CIP30 signatures on macOS
I'm working with CIP30 signatures for message signing on macOS, and need to verify that the signed message (Sig_structure in CBOR format) wraps the original message properly for this [site][1]. The Sig_structure is defined as:
Sig_structure = [
context : "Signature" / "Signature1" / "CounterSignature",
body_protected : empty_or_serialized_map,
? sign_protected : empty_or_serialized_map,
external_aad : bstr,
payload : bstr
]
any best practices ?
[1]: https://www.vgopromo.com
